Will Blazor Server ever work with Windows Authentication
(I hope this forum is the correct place to ask this question. If not, please direct me to the correct place.)
Where I work all applications must use Windows Authentication. No exceptions.
I am learning Blazor using .NET 8. I had hoped that I could use Windows Authentication with the Blazor Server App template. I am aware of the fact that Microsoft advises against using Windows Authentication in a Blazor WebAssembly application, because of that I want to use the Blazor Server App template. So, I'm not going to use a Blazor WebAssembly template, even with the Blazor Web App template. Yet, Visual Studio 2022 still doesn't allow me to use Windows Authentication with when specify server only.
So, here are my questions. Will Microsoft ever allow developers to use a Blazor Server app with Windows Authentication either now or in the future? Or is it the case that if I have to use Windows Authentication, then I have to give up on using Blazor?
